# How to realize infinite scrolling with mysql?

Tags: jquery, html, mysql

I was searching the web a lot of times, but I didn't found simple way to resolve my problem. I have got a mysql table with a lot of records. And I have got this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var screenHeight = $(window).height();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        var divHeight = $('#data').height();
        var totalHeight = screenHeight + scroll; 
        var left = divHeight - totalHeight;
        if(left < 10)
            $('#loader').html('<img src="images/loading.gif"> Loading');
            //There must be a function
    });
});
```

How to make that originally displayed on the page 10 records and when you scroll down the display 10 more records?

I have very bad English, sorry for translating.

Answer (score 1):

What you would want to do is have a counter variable in your JavaScript that will hold how many items are currently being displayed on the page. For your example, this counter will equal to 10 (10 initial items on page).

When you send an AJAX request to your server, you will include this counter variable - it will be used within the SQL query to skip over the items you are already displaying:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM items LIMIT 5, $counter ORDER BY create_time"
```

This will return 5 items but skip the first `$counter` rows (first 10 rows).

When the JavaScript receives the response, you'll count how many items you got and add that number to your counter. Your counter should now be 10 + 5.. 15...

The next time you request more content from the server, it will skip 15 items and only give you the next 5 items.

Comment: But I don't now how to create this variable and send an ajax query to mysql

Comment: @user3780736 - take it step by step. Creating a variable is as simple as `var foo = "bar"`... With regard to creating an AJAX request, I recommend looking through some existing posts here on [so] - the subject has been covered many many times.

Comment: For example I have created a variable `var foo = "bar"`, so How this foobar will help me to get records from mysql table 10 by 10 and screen it in some div?

Answer (score 0):

Scroll is like a standard pagination without click.
So your query must take parameters so you can identify which section of the records is required (from x to y)
Then you just have to append a new set of line to the end of your container.
I would advise you to first make it work without database access, appending raw static html 10 times to see the behaviour of your original code right above.

Comment: Basically I understand it, but I don't know how to realise it with php and ajax

Comment: Using the SQL given above, you should be able to trigger an ajax request to php then from php to SQL. What part is giving you hard time?
Do you know ajax and/or php db queries?

Comment: i know only php queries

Comment: I must go right now, but I advise you to find an ajax / php tutorial.
I've got some example code at home I will share with you later.